# MySQL UPDATE only updates integers, not strings

Tags: javascript, mysql, ajax, string, integer

Simple set up, insane amount of possible causes (to an inexperienced programmer such as myself, at least):

With JS I define, and later call:

```
function dbUpdate(x, y, z) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'php/dbUpdate.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: {table: x, column: y, value: z},
        success: function(html) {
        }
    });
}

dbUpdate("userbase", "currentLanguage", "en");
```

With php/dbUpdate.php, this data is caught and processed into the UPDATE query, which has worked a million times:

```
$userID = 0;

$table = ($_POST['table']);
$column = ($_POST['column']);
$value = ($_POST['value']);

mysql_query("UPDATE $table SET $column=$value WHERE id=$userID", $con);
// assume $con is defined
```

**The problem: when dbUpdate's 'z' argument is an integer (e.g., var z = 70;) then there's no problem. But when it's a simple string (e.g., var z = "en"; like above), it just won't update.**

I've checked the db's structure, and it's set to 'varchar', so it should accept strings, but hey, who am I to think I know the thing through and through.

I'm guessing it's a simple syntax thing of the kind a beginner wouldn't yet have the feel for, but I'm fed up with tweaking the syntax endlessly without result, or with result that will later shoot trouble when used in new fashion.

So here's to hoping you magnificent lot can work this out with me!

Comment: Unless you plan on using `html` in your callback function, since you have no callback use, you can remove it.

Comment: mysql_query("UPDATE $table SET $column="$value" WHERE id=$userID", $con);

Comment: If you use that, you'll get a syntax error because you are not properly concatenating your variables. Please see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out, thanks to Vlad.

But for future reference to people with the same objective:

I want dbUpdate.php to be able to handle BOTH strings and integers, so I took Vlad's advise and wrote:

```
$userID = 0;

$table = ($_POST['table']);
$column = ($_POST['column']);
$value = ($_POST['value']);

if (is_string($value)) {
    mysql_query("UPDATE $table SET $column='$value' WHERE id=$userID", $con);
}
else {
    mysql_query("UPDATE $table SET $column=$value WHERE id=$userID", $con);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping the variables:

`mysql_query("UPDATE $table SET '".$column."'='".$value."' WHERE id='".$userID.'", $con);`

Please stop using `mysql_*` functions as well, you code is easily hackable (you did not sanitize your `$_POST` values). Begin using `mysqli_*` or `PDO` asap, because what you're using is deprecated code.

Basically, you're allowing raw input into your server (client side checks can be circumvented by disabling javascript) and that is incredibly bad.

Comment: Going to try this right away, man, thanks in advance. What do you mean with sanitising my $_POST values? Thanks for all the advise!

Comment: This is a deprecated method: but in this case use `mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['whatever']);` (it would be `mysqli_real_escape_string()` for the better way to do it, but youd have to rewrite you're entire code to do that

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your id is an INT, you only need to quote your value.

```
mysql_query("UPDATE $table SET $column='$value' WHERE id=$userID", $con);
```

Comment: id is indeed an INT, but keep in mind that $value has to be able to be both strings and integers, will this quotation not cause problems for integers?

Comment: MySQL will interpret '1' as 1 if the column is type int.

Comment: Although the statement works. As @Victor mentioned, I wouldn't recommend using it in production. It is not safe at all.